# What is the best way to empty an object?

Tags: c++

Say I have the following code(this is just an example, obviously not practical):

```cpp
std::list <Object> objects;

Object cur_object;
for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
    switch(i){
        case 0:
            cur_object.foo = true;
            break;
        case 5:
        case 10:
            objects.push_back(cur_object);
            Object cur_object; //Line in question
            break;
        default:
            cur_object.bar = i;
            break;
    }
}
```

What is the most effective and efficient way to "reset" the `cur_object` for the next pass.  For example, I don't believe `cur_object = *new Object` is correct.  Would it be best for the class to have a reset method?

Solution:

After looking at perf for the suggested methods for my use case they were very close, all within 0.5% of eachother, but the accepted answer, the `objects.emplace_back()` method was the most efficient.

Comment: @churill Nope, it is used across multiple iterations of the loop before being reset

Comment: `objects.push_back(std::move(cur_object))` — but this depends on whether `Object` supports move semantics.

Comment: Something like `cur_object = {};` would work. (In some rare cases you might need to spell it as `cur_object = Object{};` or `cur_object = Object();`.)

Comment: _@Aidan_ Note that case don't constitute a fully scoped block, unless you use an extra pair of braces.

Comment: @AidanWelch Whoops, right, then `cur_object = {}` is probably the way to got. `cur_object = *new Object` would work too (in a sense),  but leaks memory.

Comment: Looking at perf, @DanielLangr 's solution seems like the most efficient, but I haven't checked if it actually resets the object or not.

Comment: Note that your question is kind-of misleading. You don't want just to reset an object. You want to insert it into a container and reset after. Which is very different if you ask about a "best" way how to do it.

Comment: That is true, I had figured that the answer would be the same as considered that the resources could be reallocated.

Comment: Okay, since I am getting a few conflicting answers tomorrow I will `perf` them all, and compare results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could circumvent that completely by simply keeping that extra object at the end of the list:

```
std::list<Object> objects;
objects.emplace_back();    // temporary object is at the end of objects

for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
    switch(i){
        case 0:
            objects.back().foo = true;
            break;
        case 5:
        case 10:
            objects.emplace_back(); // current becomes stored, add new temporary
            break;
        default:
            objects.back().bar = i;
            break;
    }
}

objects.pop_back(); // get rid of temporary
```

`pop_back` is cheap enough that it shouldn't be a problem to do it once for the entire collection, and you don't need to be concerned with moving the temporary into the list and resetting it.

Comment: Would this have any efficiency impact or is it more a matter of legibility?

Comment: @AidanWelch It might or it might not - it depends on the number of objects, the `Object` class itself and other factors. However, this solution removes the need for "resetting" the object, which is what you asked for.

Comment: The number of objects could get up to the low tens of thousands, and there are only a few properties, all strings.

Comment: If it's "low tens of thousands", why would you even care about performance here? You're using `std::list`, after all. Did you profile/measure your existing solution at all?

Comment: Yep, I could (and may) perf and compare to this.

Comment: Also, I should clarify, each individual list should never get more than at most a few thousand.  I am concerned about performance precisely because I don't want compiling each of the lists to take forever.

Comment: @AidanWelch "Forever" is typically defined as a difference between e.g. `O(n^2)` and `O(n)` and not `O(n)` and `O(n * k)`, where `k` are your optimizations here.

Comment: I couldn't think of a clever response to that, so I'll just say "Nice"

Answer (score 1):

You can use placement new to construct a new object within the storage of the old object. However, to be on the defined side of behavior, you need to turn `curObject` into a pointer:

```
char storage[sizeof(Object)];    //this is where we will store the object
Object* curObject = new(storage) Object();    //construct an Object within the storage

...

curObject->~Object();    //explicitly call destructor to tear down the old object
curObject = new(storage) Object();    //the storage can be reused now
```

The advantage of this approach is that it works even when `Object` has its assignment operators deleted.